# Synchronize Calendar-Evolution between computers

Tags: calendar

How do I sync Calendar-Evolution between laptop (Ubuntu 10-10) and desktop (Ubuntu 11-04)? Information for new Ubuntu One users provided a warning and FAQ link, but the link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, synchronizing calendar with Ubuntu One doesn't work. But you can use SyncEvolution to do that. There is also a GUI called Genesis to simplify. If you want an online solution, then you can also get an account at Funambol.com, or similar.

You could sync Evolutions data directory on Ubuntu One, but I wouldn't recommend it as it can have negative side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Read Step-by-step methods here:

[Synchronize-evolution-data-among-computers-over-lan](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/synchronize-evolution-data-among-computers-over-lan)

**Source:**  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/